# Python: Multiple CSVs

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a number of CSV files into arrays like

```
for files in folder:
    with open(files) as f:
         df = pd.read_csv(f)
         result = function(df)
         print result
```

The problem is this only reads a file at a time not multiple files. My aim is to pass each of these dataframes through a function and create an output for each dataframe. The function is done, all I need to do is read these files into separate dataframes. Is there a method to doing this?

Comment: You need to read file by file. You can't read all files at the same time - without threading.

Comment: @furas could I define dataframes like `df1,...dfN` using a `for` loop?

Comment: You can have list of dataframes - `df[0], df[1], .. df[N-1]`

Comment: @furas is it possible? something like `for i in range(len(folder)): df_%i = pd.DataFrame() % i` so I can then save my CSVs or output in these dataframes

Comment: No. Use list. `df[i] = pd.DataFrame()`

Comment: See code in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list for dataframes

```
df = []

for one_file in folder:
        with open(one_file) as f:
            df.append( pd.read_csv(f) )

print df[0]
print df[1] 
# etc.
```

or

```
df = []
result = []

for one_file in folder:
        with open(one_file) as f:
            df.append( pd.read_csv(f) )
            result.append( function(df[-1]) )
            print result[-1]

print df[0]
print df[1] 
# etc.
print df[-1] # last df

print result[0]
print result[1] 
# etc.
print result[-1] # last result
```

Comment: What does the `one_file in files` do? Why can't  i just use `files in folder`? Doesn't this just end up reading the letters in the filenames?

Comment: I thought `files` is list of files.

Comment: ah sorry. Should have made that clear. `folder = os.listdir('path')` Made slight alterations in your code and it works fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think there is no special function for filename but python is very elastic - try `df.filename = "hello_world.cvs"'` :)